# Adding Master/Detail Report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I've followed the steps from a poster on Code Project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/270924/Master-Details-Report-in-SSRS) but I'm not able to get it to work. I have 2 datasets. My report has 4 parameters:

```
@Param1
@Param2
@Param3
@Param4
```

My subreport only requires `@Param3` and `@Param4`. My parent report requires `@Param1` and `@Param2`. This parent report loads fine. But when I click on the row of which I need to expand, I get an error. I have followed the steps in the Code Project post exactly to the T. I tested my query in Management Studio and it works.

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Where should I be looking to debug?

Comment: Remove the hidden expression in Table2 and see if it works. That would be your first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: The Hidden expression is another name for the Visibility expression, so I'd start at #25 of the Code Project and make sure the parameters are named correctly, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is exactly where the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was actually happening in the Hidden expression (thanks to @Anup Agrawal and @stubaker). My expression was checking for an integer input when the data type was varchar)